# MS Access : Can we edit the Macro in VBA? and how?

Tags: ms-access, vba

**The Scenario:**
So I have a form called `FormA`, and that form has a button called `buttonA`.  When I click `buttonA` it runs a Macro that will open a form, `FormB`.

**The Question:**
Can I edit the Macro in VBA? Making it open `FormC` instead.

Comment: I'm unsure whether it's possible to edit a macro with VBA.  But, if you're willing to use VBA, I suggest you forget about the macro and use VBA code for the button's click event procedure to `DoCmd.OpenForm` your desired form.

Comment: Thanks for your gem @HansUp . I was also thinking the same, "what the heck I actually want anyway with macro?". But I hope any good idea about the editing a macro, inside the Visual Basic Editor.

Comment: I definitely agree with HansUp, I don't know if I can think of a single reason to use a macro over VBA aside from certain necessary `Auto` macros or if you can't write VBA code.

Comment: @Newd, for Access web databases, VBA is not web-compatible but certain macros are. That would be one reason to use macros over VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export the code from a macro using;

```
Application.SaveAsText acMacro, <MacroName>, <Filename>
```

and then you can import code back after editing using;

```
Application.LoadFromText acMacro, <MacroName>, <Filename>
```

The text content of the macro isn't VBA but you could probably edit it successfully.

Comment: Thanks @jhTuppeny. I'm trying my best to avoid using macro for the time being. But if I ever need edit-the-macro-thing I will start from here.